# Copying starting at offset to beginning of structure

Tags: c++, struct, offset, memcpy

So I have a structure set up like so

EDIT: PLAYERCOORDS = 1, it is defined at the beginning of my code

```
 struct PLAYERCOORDINATESSTRUCT 
{
    int type, x, y;
    bool isalive;
    bool isconnected;
    PLAYERCOORDINATESSTRUCT(int customx, int customy, bool customisalive, bool customisconnected)
    {
        type=(PLAYERCOORDS);
        x = customx;
        y = customy;
        isalive = customisalive;
        isconnected = customisconnected;
    }
    PLAYERCOORDINATESSTRUCT()
    {
        type=(PLAYERCOORDS);
    }
};

char* bufferwithstructdata = new char[sizeof(PLAYERCOORDINATESSTRUCT)-4]; 
//-4 since it's missing first int
PLAYERCOORDINATESSTRUCT testdata;
memcpy(&testdata,bufferwithstructdata,sizeof(PLAYERCOORDINATESSTRUCT)-4)
```

I have a char buffer that is holding all of the information for one of these structs, except for the int type (the first 4 bytes of the struct)

I am trying to figure out how to properly memcpy this to a source with an offset.
I found that I need to be 4 bytes off of the structure address to begin at int x.
However, I found that when I tried to add 4 to the address by doing (&testdata+4), it instead added 40 to the address! Anyone have a clue as to how I might memcpy with an offset of 4 bytes to the structure, or a way that I could just offset an address by 4 bytes instead of 10 at a time?

Thanks a lot for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is the following:

```
memcpy(((char*)&testdata)+4, bufferwithstructdata, sizeof(PLAYERCOORDINATESSTRUCT)-4);
```

The reason is because the `+` operator applied to pointers adds the integer specified times the size of the thing being pointed to. This is why adding 4 added 40 to the address. Casting to a char* before adding 4 will add 4 byte locations. Also, if you want something a bit more portable, the following would be a nice trick to do what you want:

```
memcpy(((int*)&testdata)+1, bufferwithstructdata, sizeof(PLAYERCOORDINATESSTRUCT)-4);
```

This has the benefit of adding one integer size unit to the address, regardless of the size of `int`.

As Lalaland has pointed out, it would be even better to use offsetof like so:

```
memcpy(offsetof(PLAYERCOORDINATESSTRUCT, x), bufferwithstructdata, sizeof(PLAYERCOORDINATESSTRUCT)-4);
```

Comment: Thank you so much CrazyCasta! I was so stumped XD

Comment: [offsetof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) might make this code more portable(and easier to read).